# twilio twimlresult post to sql server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, twilio

So, adapting some of the code from the tutorial here:

I have got a twilio app up and running and it correctly posts and inserts calls into my sql server, although I am trying to add additional fields to be inserted and I ran into some issues. In my controller, this is the method i am using:

```
[HttpPost]
public TwiMLResult Create(
[Bind(Include = "QuestionId,RecordingUrl,Digits,CallSid,From")]
Answer answer)
{
_answersRepository.Create(answer);
var nextQuestion = new
QuestionFinder(_questionsRepository).FindNext(answer.QuestionId);
return TwiML(nextQuestion != null ? new Response(nextQuestion).Build() :
ExitResponse);
}
```

My question is two parts. First, how can I add more fields to be added to my sql table? I tried adding `StartTime, EndTime, Duration` after `,From` and adding it to the Model, synced my database so I can see the columns on the table but nothing actually get's inserted. I put the data types as string so maybe that was the issue? I could not tell from the twilio documentation what datatype those fields wer.

The second part of the question is can I put custom fields into that `Bind(Include)` statement? For instance, can I create a variable called `Name` and then have the `TwiMLResult Create` send a string `Name` along with the twilio data with it as well? Of course, I would add it to the model class and thus to the table.

I guess my problem is is that I don't understand what is happening with the `TwiMLResult Create` method very well. What is happening exactly? This method here is what is actually RECEIVING the data coming from twilio, correct? and the `_answersRepository.Create` is what writes it to the database? So I should be able to add more fields and have them written to the db just fine I would think. I just am not sure why the `StartTime, EndTime, Duration` information isn't coming through to this point. Similarly, I am not sure how to add a custom variable, for instance, to pass the person's name to this point and have it written to the db.

I hope this all makes sense and isn't too convoluted to understand. Thank you in advance everyone! I really appreciate the help!

Syd

EDIT: Basically, I determined that those fields do not come through and thus were passing null values. To answer the second part of my question, you can definitely pass any query values and record them (which is what I ended up doing).

Comment: Is the StartTime, EndTime, and Duration being sent into this method? Someone needs to send that information in.

Comment: you're right. I think I figured something out though, so I will take the question down. Thank you for posting though!

Comment: If you figured something then you should share it so others can benefit from it.